# MS Access - Ticking record checkbox on pressing a button

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba

I am using Access 2003

I have a form that lists several payment records, the main fields are what was paid and what the bank says that was paid, with a textbox showing the difference and a checkbox to see if that payment will be processed.

Normally the user would have to manually look at the difference field then tag each record for processing and then press 'commit'.

I want to automate the process so by pressing a button all records where difference = 0 are automatically selected, so the users just needs to press 'commit'.

Comment: Is the check box bound (meaning its control source is a field in the form's record source)?

Comment: Sort of, the checkbox is there just so the event for processing knows wich records to process, but there is a field for it on the database so it knows wich records have been processed

Comment: The form contains a list. The list lists several records at once, each one with their checkboxes and textfields. I want to go trough the list and look trough each record, if the field difference is zero, mark that record checkbox and move to the next one.

Comment: is the list a subform?

Comment: No, the form detail works as the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to update the field behind the checkbox and not the checkbox itself. Here's an idea:
If you are looking for a simple solution such as putting a command button on the form and running a procedure which updates all the checkboxes you could do something like:

- Create a command button
- Place it somewhere on the form (maybe the header or footer)
- Give it a logical name
- Select the buttons properties >> events >> on Click >> event procedure
  ...and you can do something simple like the following

.

```
'Option Compare Database
'Option Explicit

'***Update a checkbox (yes\no field) depending on the value of a field***
'Table name:tblPayments
'Field name:difference
'Checkbox field name: toBeProcessed

Private Sub cmdUpdateRecords_Click()

Dim rstMyTable As DAO.Recordset 'Your table
Dim strSQL As String    'Your sql

'An SQL string based on the checkbox you want to update and the field you are assessing
strSQL = "UPDATE tblPayments SET tblPayments.toBeProcessed = IIf([difference]=0,True);"

'Execute the sql
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

'Kill the object
If IsObject(rstMyTable) Then Set rstMyTable = Nothing
Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! Keep in mind tough, it worked in my case since the table is temporary so there is no problem in directly altering data from it, but if it read data directly from a real table changing the data directly without processing would be dangerous.

Comment: You are right. This is just a simple example but if the information is sensitive, then conditions should be put in, to ensure that only certain people can run this procedure or only at certain times. Good luck.